# Package linux-image-4.4.0-65-generic needs to be reinstalled

Tags: package-management, archive

I've a very strange problem.

Yesterday everything was fine, today I've launched Ubuntu and I've got this message:

```
package linux-image-4.4.0-65-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it
```

I've searched for some solution online but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install linux-image-4.4.0-65-generic`? The "no archive" would DS like it means it's just not in your cache.

Comment: An update was offered yesterday for linux-generic for a brief time which included this kernel, but then it seems to have been pulled. One of my xenial systems got this update, the other didn't. You may have gotten caught in the transition. You shpuld probably fall back to -64. I'm not decided what to do on my one system that got this now-orphaned update.

Comment: @NonnyMoose thanks for the help but it didn't work. Anyway I've found a solution by myself.

Comment: @ Organic Marble thanks! With your suggestion I managed to find a solution!

Comment: Just download and re install the kernel using dpkg -i and you should be fine. https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/xenial/main/base/linux-image-4.4.0-65-generic

Comment: Note that the [`linux-image-4.4.0-65-generic`](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_kernel_team/xenial/main/base/linux-image-4.4.0-65-generic) was deleted from the xenial PPA repository at March of 2017. -- you cannot use `apt` or `apt-get` to install this package -- you may try to upgrade your Ubuntu and use more recent kernel versions.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution:

I installed a new kernel.

Following [this Ubuntu handbook guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/remove-old-kernels-ubuntu-16-04/) I deleted old kernels versions

After that I discovered that the linux-image-4.4.0-65-generic was in a very bad inconsistent state.

So I removed it using this command: `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <image-to-remove>`.

Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I've also followed the tip to run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <image-to-remove>.
```

However, my packages was so "corrupted" that when I ran this command I was followed by a list of dependencies that refused to remove the package. And with that upgrading the system was also a failure.

Finally I found out that I could edit /var/lib/dpkg/status and change the row of the damaged package:

```
Status: deinstall reinstreq half-installed
```

To

```
Status: install ok installed
```

With this changed, rerunning apt-get remove was suddenly successful.

A footnote of this is that in my case, it was linux-headers that needed to be reinstalled and linux-image-extra that was a dependency.

Also, after manipulating the file I've got a few warnings:

> dpkg-query: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1950 package 'linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic':
>    missing description
>
> dpkg-query: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0066' near line 7 package 'linux-headers-4.4.0-65-generic':
>    missing description

They however disappeared right after running apt-get autoremove/upgrade, so I suspect that this is not the best way of removing packages that is impossible to remove.